# Django rest framework - including an api key for access authorization

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a Restful API using Django Rest Framework, i'm not serving sensitive data but still i wanted to add some sort of authorization system for viewing my API endpoints.

Basically each user has an API key assigned, and in order to view any endpoint, the user needs to provide the key when performing any request. All the endpoints use only GET to retrieve the data, so what i did is the following:

- The API key is provided in the GET params, so something like `myURL/api/endpoint/?key=1234&filter=test`
- A middleware checks if that API key exists in my database, and if it does the user is able to get the data.

Here is my middleware:

```
TOKEN_QUERY = "key"

class TokenMiddleware(AuthenticationMiddleware):
    def process_request(self, request):

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return None
        else:     
            try:
                token = request.GET[TOKEN_QUERY]
            except Exception as e:
                # A token isn't included in the query params
                return JsonResponse({'error': 'Missing parameter: make sure to include your key.'})

            try:
                query = API_keys.objects.get(api_token=token)
            except:
                token = None

            if token != None:
                return None
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'error': 'Authentication failed. Make sure to provid a valid API key.'})
```

This system works without any problem, but i'm concerned about safety. How safe is this? Should i not use a GET request (of course i'll make sure to use HTTPS and SSL) ? Or is there a de facto way to create this kind of system? Any kind of advice is appreciated.

Comment: Over HTTPS, that should be fine but why are you not using the built-in token based authentication? I feel like you're just trying to rewrite it...

Comment: That's a good question; i didn't  look into the built in token auth in depth but i think the difference is that in this case each user has a token (stored in my db) and it will always be the same toke, it's not Django that will assign the token to the user once the request is made

Comment: The default Token auth of DRF does not expire and is also stored in DB (unlike JWT), so it just needs an initial request.  But if you prefer your way, stick to checking the Token/Key in your middleware and not in permissions as answered below.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
from rest_framework import permissions

TOKEN_QUERY = "key"

# guest token validation class    
class GuestTokenPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    def __init__(self, allowed_methods):
        self.allowed_methods = allowed_methods

    def has_permission(self, request, view):

        token = request.META.get('HTTP_GUEST_TOKEN', None)

        if token == TOKEN_QUERY:

            return request.method in self.allowed_methods

        else:

            if request.user.is_superuser:

                return request.method in self.allowed_methods
 
  # put where you want to set permission
 permission_classes = (partial(GuestTokenPermission, ['GET', 'POST', 'HEAD']),)
```

Refer https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! What i don't understand is what is the difference from what i'm doing now? I mean, in terms of safety